# Wronskian zero implies linear depen

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I don't understand the proof of Theorem 4 in these notes: https://people.math.osu.edu/kwa.1/wi11notes/3.3we.pdf

Firstly, I don't understand where Abel's theorem is used at all.
Also, going through the proof with

y_1 = x^2 for x>=0, and y_1 = 0 for x<0;

y_2 = 0 for x>= 0, and y_2 = x^2 for x<0;

it appears that the proof works for these functions, yet they are linearly independent.

Comment: The theorem is only true for solutions of the differential equation. Your $y_1$ and $y_2$ are not solutions.

Comment: Ah ok, but where is Abel's theorem needed in the proof?

Comment: Theorem 1 shows that functions are linearly independent if the Wronskian is nonzero at some point. Abel's theorem shows that being nonzero at some point is the same as being nonzero at all points (if we deal with solutions). This is the only place in the proof where it is needed.

Comment: At the start of the proof of theorem 4 it says 'By Abel's Theorem, W being nonzero for all t, and W=0 identically are mutually exclusive'. Surely these events are mutually exclusive whether we have Abel's Theorem or not?

Comment: A misfortunate wording. Sure they exclude each other, but what they intended to say is that no other case it possible, i.e. that the Wronskian cannot be zero at some point and nonzero at some other point.

Answer (score 1):

A property of a determinant is that if 2 colums are lineary demendent that te determinant is zero. This ofcource only gives us a proof for a certain $x_o$ for which $W(y_0,y_1)(x_0) = 0$. We now want to expand this to $\forall x \in \mathbb{I}$.

We will use (5) from your paper, that is: $$ W(y_0,y_1) = C \cdot \exp\left( \int p(t)dt \right) $$

We know that the exponential is never zero. So: $W(y_0,y_1) = C \cdot a$ with $a = \exp\left( \int p(t)dt \right)$ and thus $a \neq 0$

We have already established that  $\exists x_0 \in \mathbb{I}.W(y_0,y_1)(x_0) = 0$ . This means that $C$ must be zero, if this wasn't the case $W$ could never equal zero. So $W(y_0,y_1) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{I}$.

If $y_0$ and $y_1$ were independent, $W(y_0,y_1) \neq 0$. this means that $C \neq 0$for all $x \in \mathbb{I}$

Thus we have: $$
(\exists x_z \in \mathbb{I}:W(y_0,y_1)=0) \implies (\forall x \in \mathbb{I}:W(y_0,y_1)=0) \\
(\exists x_z \in \mathbb{I}:W(y_0,y_1) \neq 0) \implies (\forall x \in \mathbb{I}:W(y_0,y_1) \neq 0)
$$

---

BTW: There is an error in the book. The are actualy using [Abel's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_identity)

Comment: Could we not say that if there is one point, p, at which the wronskian is 0, then the matrix is singular at that point so there exist constants a, b such that ay_1(p) + by_2(p) = 0 with a, b not both zero. Then taking y(x) = ay_1(x) + by_2(x) gives y(p) = 0 and y'(p) = 0. So we only need W=0 at one point.

Comment: @user152440 You are right.